# Can you assign variables this way?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to do something like this in JS?

```
var vehicleTable, journeyTable, alertTable, maintenanceTable;
var infoTablesVars = [vehicleTable, journeyTable, alertTable, maintenanceTable];

for (var x = 0; x < infoTablesVars.length; x++){
    infoTablesVars[x] = x;            
}
```

EDIT:

For the wise guys, I did try it out. Here's what I'm actually trying to do:

```
$(function(){
                    vehicleTable = $('#table_vehicleInfo').dataTable({
                        "bInfo": false,
                        "bFilter": false,
                        "bSort": false,
                        "bPaginate": false,
                        "bJQueryUI": true,
                        "bAutoScroll": true,
                        "bAutoWidth": true,
                        "sScrollY": "75px",
                        "sScrollX": "100%"
                    });  //end vehicleTable

                    maintenanceTable = $('#table_maintenanceInfo').dataTable({
                        "bInfo": false,
                        "bFilter": false,
                        "bSort": false,
                        "bPaginate": false,
                        "bJQueryUI": true,
                        "bAutoScroll": true,
                        "bAutoWidth": true,
                        "sScrollY": "75px",
                        "sScrollX": "100%"
                    });  //end maintenanceTable

                    journeyTable = $('#table_journeyInfo').dataTable({
                        "bInfo": false,
                        "bFilter": false,
                        "bSort": false,
                        "bPaginate": false,
                        "bJQueryUI": true,
                        "bAutoScroll": true,
                        "bAutoWidth": true,
                        "sScrollY": "75px",
                        "sScrollX": "100%"
                    });  //end journeyTable

                    alertTable = $('#table_alertInfo').dataTable({
                        "bInfo": false,
                        "bFilter": false,
                        "bSort": false,
                        "bPaginate": false,
                        "bJQueryUI": true,
                        "bAutoScroll": true,
                        "bAutoWidth": true,
                        "sScrollY": "75px",
                        "sScrollX": "100%"
                    });  //end alertTable

                });  //end function()
```

To this:

```
var infoTablesVars = [vehicleTable, journeyTable, alertTable, maintenanceTable];


var infoTables = ['#table_vehicleInfo', '#table_journeyInfo', '#table_alertInfo', '#table_maintenanceInfo'];

 $(function(){

                    for (var x = 0; x < infoTablesVars.length; x++){

                        infoTablesVars[x] = $(infoTables[x]).dataTable({
                        "bInfo": false,
                        "bFilter": false,
                        "bSort": false,
                        "bPaginate": false,
                        "bJQueryUI": true,
                        "bAutoScroll": true,
                        "bAutoWidth": true,
                        "sScrollY": "75px",
                        "sScrollX": "100%"
                        });
                    }

                });  //end function()
```

The assignment never occurs in the second section.

Comment: If you need such, simply always use objects and their properties, no variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize array, but considering each index is always a particular variable is only possible if you handle it via code, your given code should be:

```
var infoTablesVars = [];

for (var x = 0; x < 4; x++){
    infoTablesVars[x] = x;            
}
```

[Here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X2ed3/2/)

Or you can also try, [See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X2ed3/1/):

```
var vehicleTable=2, journeyTable=4, alertTable=50, maintenanceTable=67;
var infoTablesVars = [vehicleTable, journeyTable, alertTable, maintenanceTable];
```

Comment: If we already know variable to put in array, we can use it for maxlength.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that this way, but this one will works (but it's dirty and I recommend you to reconsider the question and find another way) :

```
var vehicleTable, journeyTable, alertTable, maintenanceTable;
var infoTablesVars = ["vehicleTable", "journeyTable", "alertTable", "maintenanceTable"];

for (var x = 0; x < infoTablesVars.length; x++){
    self[infoTablesVars[x]] = x;            
}
```

Comment: Please explain what `self` is and how that works, to show *why* it's bad practise.